# How to efficiently map an epoll fd to a context?

Tags: c, linux, posix, epoll

Assume there is a typical context struct that holds the information about a socket connection.

```c
struct widget_ctx_t{
    int socket;
    char widgetname[MAXWIDGET];
    ...
}
```

Assume there are thousands of connections to widgets, all with a corresponding context.

```c
struct widget_ctx_t Widgets[5000]
```

From what I have read, `epoll` should be used to monitor all the sockets in `Widgets`. Epoll will return the socket when data is sent to it.

Does this mean that when epoll returns a socket file descriptor, do I need to search all the `Widgets` in order to find the one that has the file descriptor? IE:

```c
if (events[n].events & EPOLLIN) {
    for(int i = 0; i < MAXWIDGET; i++ ){
            if(events[n].data.fd == Widgets[i].socket){
                //Ok so that is the context to this socket
        }
    }
...
}
```

Or is there a way to get epoll to provide this context for me?

Answer (score 3):

The `data` member of the `epoll_event` structure is a union with a few different fields, including a `void *ptr` one. Use it instead of `fd` - assign the address of the relevant `widget_ctx_t` object to it when adding a descriptor to the watch list with `epoll_ctl()`, and use that when handling events returned by `epoll_wait()`:

```c
struct epoll_event event;
event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT;
event.data.ptr = &Widgets[n];
epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, Widgets[n].socket, &event);
```

and later

```c
if (events[n].events & EPOLLIN) {
    struct widget_ctx_t *ctx = events[n].data.ptr;
    // Do something with ctx
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer and something most tutorials actually fail to mention; one can set arbitrary event.data. One can even make the returned file descriptor to point to something else than what descriptor epoll actually noticed activity in.